# Use system default proxy with c#

Tags: c#, proxy

I am currently using an application as tuxler from https://tuxler.com/ to pass through a proxy to browse the internet.

I wanted to know if its possible via c# to also use that proxy to download a web page. I tried a few items, one of them is below:-

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.UseProxy = true;
handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
handler.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
var client = new HttpClient(handler);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 Bla");
response = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(page);
```

So basically what i want to do is a c# code to use the same proxy as my browser is using.

Comment: Is that code not working in some way? Are you getting exceptions/errors? You should explain what the issue is more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

**Tuxler** is VPN based on google extension, so you can use it only in *Chrome browser*.

Try some other VPN with desktop application like:  [Windscribe](https://windscribe.com/) (free) or OpenVPN (you need configs for VPN).

All traffic from your computer will be pushed through a VPN. You don't need to setup anything in c# code.